# Multiple insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

When I use this code, I get one record for each id stored in the users table. Instead, I want to be able to insert only 1 record each time, the one that matches the logged users id.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$acname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ACName']);
$btu = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['BTU']);
$space = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Space']);
$energyclass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['EnergyClass']);



$sql="INSERT INTO aircondition (id, ACName, BTU, Space,  EnergyClass)
SELECT id, '$acname', '$btu', '$space', '$energyclass'
FROM  users";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
header('location:aircondition.php');


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a where clause in  your select statement

```
$sql="INSERT INTO aircondition (id, ACName, BTU, Space,  EnergyClass)
SELECT id, '$acname', '$btu', '$space', '$energyclass'
FROM  users WHERE usernamecolumn= currentusername ;
```

Comment: The problem is that when I am logged as a user with id 2,for example, and I try to insert a new value in the table, the result will be one value for each id inserted in the users table.How am I supposed to define the currently logged in id?

Comment: you can put it in a seesion variable when y ou logged in. Then use that variable when ever you want to get the current user

Comment: Something like this could work?

    mysql_select_db("my_db",$conn);
    $sql="select * from users where name='$_GET[userlogin]' and       password='$_GET[password]'";
    $_SESSION['id']='id'; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());